# Solving inequality of $ \log_{10}{(2x-5)} < \log_{1\over10}{(x-3)} $

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have a problem to solving this inequality
$$ \log_{10}{(2x-5)} < \log_{1\over10}{(x-3)} $$
My work so far is

Step 1 : Finding the definition term of $\log_{10}{(2x-5)}$
$$2x-5 > 0$$
$$2x>5$$
$$x>\frac{5}{2}$$

Step 2: Finding the definition term of $\log_{1\over10}{(x-3)}$
$$x-3>0$$
$$x>3$$

Step 3 : Finding the inequality term
$$\log_{10}{(2x-5)} < \log_{1\over10}{(x-3)}$$
$$\log_{10}{(2x-5)} < \frac{1}{\log_{10}{(x-3)}}  $$

From this position, i am confused, what should i do for the next step?
Thank you for your help, sir.

After reading all suggestion, i try to redo my work also i realize my mistake in step 3.

Step 3 : 
$$ \log_{10}{(2x-5)} < \log_{1\over10}{x-3}  $$
$$ \log_{10}{(2x-5)} < \log_{10}{(\frac{1}{x-3})}  $$
$$ (2x-5) < \frac{1}{(x-3)}$$
$$ (2x-5)(x-3) < 1 $$
$$ 2x^2 -6x-5x+15 < 1 $$
$$ 2x^2-11x+15<1$$
$$2x^2-11x+15-1<0$$
$$2x^2-11x+14<0$$
$$(x-2)(2x-7)<0$$
$$2<x<\frac{7}{2}$$

Step 4: Finding the set of solutions in real number.
Affect from definition term in step 1 to inequality term in step 3.
$$ \frac{5}{2} < x< \frac{7}{2} $$
Affect from definition term in step 2 to inequality term in step 3.
$$ 3 < x < \frac{7}{2} $$
$\therefore $ the set of solution is
$\left(3<x<\frac{7}{2}, x \in R \right) $
Thanks for suggestion and explanation.

Comment: Try using $$\log_b(a)=\frac{\log_c(a)}{\log_c(b)}$$ which is true for literally any $c>0$. Also, it’s easier to convert them both to a new base rather than converting one to the base of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that all logarithms are defined (so $x>3$). Let $a=\log_{10} (2x-5)$ and $b=\log_{1/10} (x-3)$ . Then $10^{a}=2x-5$ and $10^{b}=\frac 1 {x-3}$. The inequality $a <b$ is equivalent to. $10^{a} <10^{b}$. So we can write the given inequality as $(2x-5)(x-3)<1$. Can you proceed from here?

The answer is $3<x<3.5$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we need $x>$max$(5/2,3)=3$

to keep $\log_{10}(2x-5),\log_{1/10}(x-3)$ real

$$\log_{10}(2x-5)<\log_{1/10}(x-3)=-\log_{10}(x-3)$$  as $\dfrac1{10}=10^{-1}$

$$\iff0>\log_{10}(2x-5)+\log_{10}(x-3)=\log_{10}(2x-5)(x-3)$$

$$\iff(2x-5)(x-3)<10^0=1$$

$$\iff2x^2-11x+14<0$$

$$\iff(2x-7)(x-2)<0$$

$$\implies2<x<\dfrac72$$

But we need to honor $x>3$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Steps 1 and 2 are good.
However, there is a mistake on step 3. $\log_{1/10}(x-3)$ is not equal to $\frac{1}{\log_{10}(x-3)}$. You should go back to napierian logarithm with
$$ \log_{1/10} (x-3) = \frac{\ln(x-3)}{\ln(1/10)} = \frac{\ln(x-3)}{- \ln(10)}$$
$$ \log_{10} (2x-5) = \frac{\ln(2x-5)}{\ln(10)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Be careful in your last step. According to the change of base formula:

$$\log_{1\over10}{(x-3)} = \frac{\log_{10} (x-3) }{\log_{10} (\frac{1}{10})} = -\log_{10} (x-3) \ne \frac{1}{\log_{10}{(x-3)}}$$

So you should have instead:
$$\log_{10} (2x-5) < -\log_{10} (x-3)$$
$$10^{\log_{10} (2x-5)} < 10^{\log_{10} (x-3) \times-1}$$

Now simplify the right-hand side, and you should get a nice quadratic equation.